# Why can't I append the file as one of the parameter value in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, post, file-upload, alamofire

I want to know why can't I give a file as one of the parameter values and to send the parameter as an upload request in Alamofire. I tried like this and it works.

```
let parameters: [String : AnyObject ] = [
        "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "password" : "password",
        "full_name": "XXX"]

let image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "logo.png")

    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        "http://myurl.com/register",
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
              }

                if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1) {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "profile_pic", fileName: "logo.png", mimeType: "image/png")
              }
       },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

Why can't I pass the image as a parameter value? And also why should I need to change the image in `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

If I pass the image as a value without changing the representation, error throws that it is not in `NSData` format.

Note that the request should pass even if there is an image or not, because it is an optional one.

Comment: What's the error you got when you tried with parameter?

Comment: Says that `UIImage is not sent to an instance of type String` I need to store the value of the image in the parameter and to check the image available or not via optional chaining in the **for loop** itself. But here I'm checking the image is available or not, separately. Could you understand what I'm trying to convey?!

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `Alamofire` just a library to help you to process a `NSURLRequest`. This is a common way that client can communicate with server via a HTTP request. Other platforms (such as Android, Desktop, or Web...) also use this way, too. So they must be same format. The `post body` only accepts simple data format such as String, Int, or byte[]... It does not know what is `UIImage`, but `NSData`. NSData is a format of byte[].

So, if you want to upload a text file, or a video, you have to convert it to `NSData`, too.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks man! you clarified my doubt!!. But could you answer my question which i commented for **zcui93** comment?!

Comment: I don't know what you want :)